# Rails 6 application with two base controller: one inherits from ActionController::Base and other ActionController::API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-6

Would it be possible to have a Rails 6 application controller with two different base classes to support lightweight API mobile application/SPA and others to support form rendering like active admin, dashboard?

Something like below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include CommonModule
end

class Api::ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include CommonModule
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is 2 "application controllers", each with different base classes. But, yes you can do what you have written in your question.

You can then have controllers within the API namespace which inherit from Api::ApplicationController (and therefore from ActionController::API) and have controllers which inherit from ApplicationController (and the fuller ActionController::Base)